# Передача порядка байт, определённых длин по Uart Python (GTM-5110c31)

Tags: python, структуры-данных, serial

Есть устройство, которое работает по Uart и принимает команды в таком виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Полная документация](http://www.holtek.com.tw/documents/10179/b198ecbe-64f7-4469-bcbe-d40d7ed1fd48)

Есть готова библиотека на C++, которая прекрасно работает, принцип отправки команды:

```
#define BYTE unsigned char
#define WORD unsigned int
#define DWORD unsigned long

#define STX1  0x55  //Header1
#define STX2  0xAA  //Header2
#define SB_OEM_PKT_SIZE  12
#define SB_OEM_CHK_SUM_SIZE  2
enum {CMD_OPEN = 0x01}


typedef struct {
    BYTE    Head1;
    BYTE    Head2;
    WORD    wDevId;
    DWORD   nParam;
    WORD    wCmd;// or nAck
    WORD    wChkSum;
} SB_OEM_PKT;

WORD CalcChkSumOfCmdAckPkt( SB_OEM_PKT* pPkt ){
    WORD wChkSum = 0;
    BYTE* pBuf = (BYTE*)pPkt;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(SB_OEM_PKT)-SB_OEM_CHK_SUM_SIZE);i++){
        wChkSum += pBuf[i];
    }
    return wChkSum;
}

void SendCmdOrAck(WORD wDevID, WORD wCmdOrAck, DWORD nParam) {
    SB_OEM_PKT pkt;
    int nSentBytes;

    pkt.Head1 = (BYTE)STX1;
    pkt.Head2 = (BYTE)STX2;
    pkt.wDevId = wDevID;
    pkt.wCmd = wCmdOrAck;
    pkt.nParam = nParam;
    pkt.wChkSum = CalcChkSumOfCmdAckPkt( &pkt );

    nSentBytes = gtmSerial->write( (BYTE*)&pkt,SB_OEM_PKT_SIZE);
}

WORD gwDevID = 1;
int main(){
    SendCmdOrAck(gwDevID, CMD_OPEN, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

[Полностью библиотека](https://github.com/oopsmonk/arduino-finger-dev)

На как реализовать отправку такого типа на Python?
Пытался упаковать через struct:

```
ser.write(pack('<BBILII', 0x55,0xAA,0x0001,1,1,258))
```

Но модуль возвращает ошибку(по uart назад присылает ответ, обозначающий ошибку).
Подскажите как это реализовать на python?
Буду рад любой помощи, даже догадок.

Comment: Можно посмотреть что реально уходит в порт и сравнить для питона и для сей, например...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
ser.write(pack('<BBHLHH', 0x55, 0xAA, 0x0001, 0, 1, 258)
```

Какие были проблемы:

- В формате данных `I` имеет длину 4, а по таблице из документации, должен иметь длину 2, заменил на `H`
- Номера команд были в HEX, а я передавал их в INT, использую функцию:
  `int(str(cmd), 16)`

Это был модуль для сканирования отпечатка пальца **GTM-5110c31**, возможно кому-то пригодится программа для работы с ним:

```
import time
import serial
from struct import *

def send_cmd(parm,cmd):
    check = 0x55+0xAA+0x0001+parm+cmd;
    ser.write(pack('<BBHLHH', 0x55, 0xAA, 0x0001, parm, cmd, check))
    while ser.inWaiting() < 12: time.sleep(0.05)
    info = unpack('<BBHLHH',ser.read(ser.inWaiting()));
    if(info[0]+info[1]+info[2]+info[3]+info[4] != info[5]): print('Error checksumm',info)
    elif info[4] != 48: print('Error response key',info)
    else: print('Ok',info)

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS1',
    baudrate=9600
)
ser.close()
ser.open()
print(ser.isOpen())

send_cmd(0x0,0x1) #Open

send_cmd(0x1,0x12) #CmosLed ON

ser.close()
```

Comment: Для читаемости, можно явно структуру создать, [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17246128/4279)

Comment: @jfs, дело в том что в документации номера команд и параметров указанны в HEX, так удобнее при написании кода: http://joxi.ru/LQ2K6GxTBzEwmj.jpg

Comment: @jfs кажется я понял что вы имели ввиду, похоже вы правы, лучше будет сразу указывать с `0x`